# Get link to media from AVFullScreenViewController iOS 8

Tags: ios, objective-c, avplayer

i'am trying to get links to video when something begin to play (for example any YouTube video).

First i catch when video begin to play

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(videoStarted:) name:@"UIWindowDidBecomeVisibleNotification" object:nil];
```

then with delay try to get link

```
-(void)videoStarted:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    NSLog(@"notification dic = %@", [notification userInfo]);
    [self performSelector:@selector(detectModal) withObject:nil afterDelay:2.5f];
}

-(void)detectModal
{
    CUViewController *controller = (CUViewController *)[appDelegate.window rootViewController].presentedViewController;
    NSLog(@"Presented modal = %@", [appDelegate.window rootViewController].presentedViewController);
    if(controller && [controller respondsToSelector:@selector(item)])
    {
        id currentItem = [controller item];
        if(currentItem && [currentItem respondsToSelector:@selector(asset)])
        {
            AVURLAsset *asset = (AVURLAsset *)[currentItem asset];
            if([asset respondsToSelector:@selector(URL)] && asset.URL)
                [self newLinkDetected:[[asset URL] absoluteString]];
            NSLog(@"asset find = %@", asset);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        for (UIWindow *window in [UIApplication sharedApplication].windows) {
            if ([window.rootViewController.presentedViewController isKindOfClass:NSClassFromString(@"AVFullScreenViewController")])
            {
                controller = (CUViewController *)window.rootViewController.presentedViewController;
                for(int i = 0; i < [controller.view.subviews count]; i++)
                {
                    UIView *topView = [controller.view.subviews objectAtIndex:i];
                    NSLog(@"top view = %@", topView);
                    for(int j = 0; j < [topView.subviews count]; j++)
                    {
                        UIView *subView = [topView.subviews objectAtIndex:j];
                        NSLog(@"sub view = %@", subView);
                        for (int k = 0; k < [subView.subviews count]; k++)
                        {
                            CUPlayerView *subsubView = (CUPlayerView *)[subView.subviews objectAtIndex:k];
                            NSLog(@"sub sub view = %@ class = %@", subsubView, NSStringFromClass([subsubView class]));
                            if([NSStringFromClass([subsubView class]) isEqualToString:@"AVVideoLayerView"])
                            {
                                NSLog(@"player view controller = %@", subsubView.playerController);
                                CUPlayerController *pController = subsubView.playerController;
                                NSLog(@"item = %@", [pController player]);
                                CUPlayerController *proxyPlayer = pController.playerControllerProxy;
                                if(proxyPlayer)
                                {
                                    AVPlayer *player = [proxyPlayer player];
                                    NSLog(@"find player = %@ chapters = %@", player, proxyPlayer.contentChapters);
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

CUViewController, CUPlayerView, CUPlayerController - fake classes it's and looks like this

```
@interface CUPlayerController : UIViewController

@property(nonatomic, retain) id playerControllerProxy;
@property(nonatomic, retain) id player;
@property(nonatomic, retain) id item;

- (id)contentChapters;

@end
```

everything is okay until this line

```
NSLog(@"find player = %@ chapters = %@", player, proxyPlayer.contentChapters);
```

player is always nil. Maybe there is a more simple way to get link to media?

Comment: You want to get the URL of the video which is being played in a browser or did I misunderstand you?

Comment: yes, that starts playing from uiwebview

Comment: If you want to download the video afterwards, I'll have to tell you, that Apple will reject your application. [Mercury Browser](http://mercury-browser.com/) did the same and had to remove this feature.

Comment: I know how to pass that.

Comment: I did the same few years ago with iOS 4. I'll have a look at it.

Comment: No, Proxy isn't nil, but in it AVPlayer is nil. I've found solution but it's very dirty, i rather say very dirty hack, scan all app's memory for instance of NSURLAsset.

Answer (score 0):

First off I'd like to focus on your AVPlayer which plays an AVPlayerItem. An AVPlayerItem object carries a reference to an AVAsset object and presentation settings for that asset. When you use the *playerWithURL:* method of AVPlayer it automatically creates the AVPlayerItem backed by an asset that is a subclass of AVAsset named AVURLAsset. AVURLAsset has a URL property. So if you use that you can get the NSURL of the currently playing item. Here's an example function of getting URL:

```
-(NSURL *)urlOfCurrentlyPlayingInPlayer:(AVPlayer *)player{
    // get current asset
    AVAsset *currentPlayerAsset = player.currentItem.asset;
    // make sure the current asset is an AVURLAsset
    if (![currentPlayerAsset isKindOfClass:AVURLAsset.class]) return nil;
    // return the NSURL
    return [(AVURLAsset *)currentPlayerAsset URL];
}
```

I think it's just a matter of how you fit this thing around your code. Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi, it's seems that you didn't read the question. I'm try to get video's URL which was started from UIWebView.